# File copier remote node TMPDIR (RD_FILE_COPY_DESTINATION)

Tags: rundeck

I'm looking a way to "transfer" some files on each execution node. My best think is to use the temporary directory that copier uses to transfer inline scripts contents. I need warranty that this fiolder will be deleted after execution, or in failed job state.This seems to have the following structure
`/tmp/PROCESS-ID-JOB-EXEC-ID-NODE-NAME-dispatch-script.tmp.sh`. Example : /tmp/8227-122706-localhost-dispatch-script.tmp.sh

Looking at openssh node executor plugin, found that, the copy part of the plugin (ssh-copy.sh) have $RD_FILE_COPY_DESTINATION and $RD_FILE_COPY_FILE variables, that define the above filename. Seems like some env variables, but I don't whereis this two variables source.

Question:
Is there any variable that I can use in inline scripts and copy step to use the temporary directory created by rundeck (Example : /tmp/8227-122706-localhost-dispatch-script.tmp.sh).

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own project-wide (on the project configuration file) or system-wide (on the `framework.properties` file) variables, e.g: you can add a project-wide by clicking on Project Settings (left) > Edit Configuration > Edit Configuration File (right button), and then add your variable: `project.globals.mypath=/custom/path`.

You can use it in three ways: `${globals.mypath}` on the command step, `@globals.mypath@` on the inline script step, and `$RD_GLOBALS_MYPATH` on "external" script steps.

Same if you decide to use globals across all Rundeck projects, just define them on the `framework.properties` file (located at the `/etc/rundeck` path) in the following way: `framework.globals.mypath=/custom/path` and call them in the same three ways explained before.

More info [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/config-file-reference.html#global-execution-variables).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I need to know , how can I refer to rundeck tmpdir, because, I need warranties that tmpdir contents should be empty, after workflow execution. I can "mimic" this behaviour with trap inside a inline step, but should be more elaborate if workflow hace more than 2 steps. This is the main reason for using "own" rundeck filecopier TMPDIR